# PHP MySQLi While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am facing some problems when creating my while loop within PHP.
I want to be able to pull data out from multiple tables within a while loop. For example I have a table called Invoices and a second table called Customers. Both tables have a field named Email, and whenever I am trying to print or echo that row, then I only get one of them.. Maybe you could have a look at my code.

```
    <?
    $invoice_edit_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM invoices, customers 
    WHERE invoice.customer_id = kunder.id AND
    invoices.kunde_id = '$_GET[edit]' AND
    invoices.invoice_year = '$_GET[year]' AND
    invoices.invoice_nr = '$_GET[nr]'") or die(mysqli_error($db));

    while($row = $invoice_edit_query->fetch_object()){
        ?>
        <td>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<? print $row->email; ?>"></td>
        <?
    }
    ?>
```

Is there a way to print the values of my tables like the WHERE statement invoices.email or customers.email? Maybe instead of writing:

```
    $row->email;
```

then writing:

```
    $row->invoices.email;
```

Comment: I suggest to use an ORM, such as, Doctirine or Yii's ActiveRecord

Comment: what does it show if you `var_dump($row)` inside your loop?

Comment: This is what I get (tables, rows and such were translated from danish to english before though):

object(stdClass)#6 (22) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["kunde_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["faktura_aar"]=> string(4) "2014" ["faktura_nr"]=> string(3) "006" ["dato"]=> string(10) "2014-02-10" ["debitor"]=> NULL ["reference"]=> NULL ["forsikringsselskab"]=> NULL ["attention"]=> NULL ["email"]=> string(21)}

Comment: Sorry to point this out but, you're using unsanitised $_GET data in your queries, which leaves you at risk to SQL injection: http://ie1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: I've got functions that sanitize all of my data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias the fields so that you can reference them seperately:

```
<?php
$id = (int) $_GET['edit'];
$year = (int) $_GET['year'];
$nr = (int) $_GET['nr'];

$sql = "SELECT customer.email as customer_email, invoices.email as invoices_email, * FROM invoices  
JOIN customers on  customer.customer_id = invoices.id 
WHERE 
invoices.kunde_id = '$id' AND
invoices.invoice_year = '$year' AND
invoices.invoice_nr = '$nr'";
$invoice_edit_query = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $invoice_edit_query->fetch_object()){
    ?>
    <td>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<? print $row->customer_email; ?>"></td>
    <?
}
?>
```

Note I've also added some rudimentary testing to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you very much! One question though, why should I use JOIN instead?

Comment: Using JOIN is easier to read than looking at a set of WHERE criteria. As well as that, if you use JOIN (and are combining rows from more than 2 tables) you can control the order in which the data gets combined together and finally you can allow for scenarios where some of the data may not be present in both tables concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Try "`SELECT invoices.email as email1, customers.email as email2, other fields FROM`"... and then print those out.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, but isn't their a way to SELECT * FROM those tables instead of having to type in every single field?

Comment: Try   SELECT invoices.email as email1, customers.email as email2, *    ... I don't know if it works :P

Comment: Yes, seems to be working fine, but still a mess to type in every field.. By the way, I had to type SELECT invoices.email as email1, customers.email as email2, invoices.*, customers.* FROM...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have done same thing in my project.

```
protected function _dynamicBindResult($stmt)
{
    $parameter = array();
    $result = array();

    //get list of all columns in Parameter array
    $count = $stmt->columnCount();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $temp = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
        $parameter[] = $temp['name'];
    }

    //now filter row on basis of parameter array
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $x = array();

        foreach ($parameter as $key => $column) {
            $x[$column] = $row[$column];
        }
        $result[] = $x;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Call this function _dynamicBindResult in your project & pass $row as parameter. Then you can use $result->column_name.

Try it. I hope it will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's 'DESCRIBE' functionality to get all of the field names.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html

You can 'DESCRIBE' a table and it will give you each of the fields in the 'Field' column.  Loop through each field and add it to your query.